# Screen dimensions coherent with window dimensions in Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I have a problem with screen configuration in Python Tkinter. I want a wallpaper that is compatible with the size of the window in which I open it. I made this function:

```
def resizer(e):
    global bg1, resized_bg, new_bg
    bg1 = Image.open("WUT_banner_Automotive_1080x335.4532699.png")
    resized_bg = bg1.resize((e.width, e.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bg)
    my_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=new_bg, anchor="nw")
```

It works well when I call it in the "main", but when I call it in another function it doesn't work:

```
def log_ok():
    user = e1.get()
    password = e2.get()

    if(user == "" and password == ""):
        messagebox.showinfo("", "Inserisci le credenziali per accedere.")

    elif(user == "admin" and password == "admin"):
        messagebox.showinfo("", "Login success.")
        root.destroy()
        s = Tk()
        s.title("Service window")
        s.geometry("700x400")
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="WUT_banner_Automotive_1080x335.4532699.png")
        my_canvas = Canvas(s, width = 700, heigh =335)
        my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        my_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=bg, anchor="nw")
        Button(s, text="Diagnostic request", command = lambda: [ s.destroy(),open_window() ] , heigh = 3, width = 13).place(x=10, y=100)




        .bind('<Configure>', resizer)
        s.mainloop()
    
       
        
        

    else:
        messagebox.showerror("", "Incorrect Username and Password")`
```

In particular, I obtain this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yPn4.png)

Can you kindly say me where am I wrong? I can't see error and I've been hitting my head for almost two days about how to make a wallpaper suitable for a window but in another function. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have multiple instances of `Tk()`, you need to pass in the master parameter when creating a `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. So you need to add `master = my_canvas` to `new_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bg)` and something similar for all of your other `ImageTk.PhotoImage`s

Comment: You have passed `root` to `Canvas(...)`, but `root` has been destroyed.

Comment: Okay, but the s window must open ONLY when there is the elif condition, so I don't know how to solve the issue...

Comment: @acw1668 Okay sorry, I was wrong only to copy, when I recall s in canvas, however I get an error (even if a non-resizable background is created):  return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

Comment: I think `my_canvas` inside `resizer()` refers to the one created in `root` window, so it is destroyed along with `root`.  Note that `my_canvas` inside `log_ok()` is a local variable.